# I am having problem : loading static files in HTML code in a Django Project . As I know for a href link we use "{% static 'addressOfFile' %}"

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-template-filters, django-static

[these image are in static folder of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVtje.jpg)

```html
<div id="demo-1" data-zs-src='["images/b1.jpg","images/b5.jpg","images/b2.jpg","images/b3.jpg","images/b4.jpg","images/b6.jpg"]>
```

'How to use django template language to load these images in data-zs-src attribute . if it was data-zs-src="images/b1.jpg"  then it would be easy like data-zs-source="{% static 'images/b1.jpg' %}" .  but I have double quatation inside single quatation . so it is not working . plz help me with right code

Comment: "but I have double quatation inside single quatation . so it is not working" => Django doesn't care about the quotations around the templatetag so that's not the issue. Please explain how it's "not working".

Comment: You need to load `static` before using it. Please read the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: @Wariored I have loaded static at the top of my html file . thats not the issue . other static files are loading without any issue .

Comment: as i  did for this - <a href=" {% static 'index.html' %}">

Comment: how can i do for this  - <div id="demo-1" data-zs-src='["images/b1.jpg","images/b5.jpg","images/b2.jpg","images/b3.jpg","images/b4.jpg","images/b6.jpg"]' >

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers